# CodeIgniter - An auth library with these features

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I’m searching for a CI auth library with these features or at least most of them:

- Social login with support for Google, Twitter, Facebook where if an user sign up the normal way then if he logs in with he’s google account the two account will be merged if he’s using the same email
- Normal sign up:

  - remember me
  - password recovery
  - captcha
  - quite secure

I don’t need role-based system.

I’ve seen various library especially:

- a3m - http://code.google.com/p/a3m/ but it’s not updated since february
- tank auth + xta 2 (http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/ - http://xta2.ericbae.com/index.php/auth/login also them are not updated since 3-5 months

What do you recommend?

Comment: FYI, a3m is reborn as `a3m bootstrapped` => https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M

Answer (score 5):

I recently looked for a system with similar requirements. I found the [A3M](http://code.google.com/p/a3m/) library, (which is an intended role-based system, but isn't functional), and though it hasn't been recently updated, I was able to successfully incorporate it into my latest project with some minor edits. If you feel comfortable with being able to edit the library to fit your needs (which is quite easy to understand), then I'd recommend this system. A3M matches all of your requirements, and runs many security checks for code congruency.

Comment: But it has the feature so that signing in with multiple services but using the same email all the accounts get together like what happend here on stack overflow?

Comment: Yes it does! A3M uses different tables to separate the different _types_ of accounts, but they all point to the same user.

Comment: but it seem really abandoned! i've found also ion auth which is still supported but has no extension for twitter, facebook, google

Comment: There is no documentation provided, nor do I believe there is any **new** tutorial for CI 2.0, but if you are comfortable with editing code, it should be fairly easy. I found much of the library to be self explanatory in class, function, and method naming.